# How do I get the offset of an element from the current screen position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to refactor out all my jQuery with pure Javascript, I got everything working except a very specific value. I'm getting a different value depending in the browser vendor for this code :

With jQuery I'd use:

```
var topSelected = figure.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
```

Here is my (non working) attempt using the DOM without jQuery:

```
 var rect = figure.getBoundingClientRect(),
     topSelected = (rect.top + document.body.scrollTop) - window.pageYOffset;
```

I'm getting the exact same value for topSelected in Chrome with this code, but not for FF. The value that differs from browser to browser is `document.body.scrollTop`.

What is the correct way to get the difference between the offset of an element and the scroll top using the DOM API?

I need to support IE9+, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: *"I'm trying to replace all jQuery with pure Javascript"* No, you're trying to replace your use of jQuery with pure *DOM*. Both use JavaScript.

Comment: Since jQuery is pure JavaScript, you can just look at the part that says `scrollTop` and check if it does anything different than getting `pageYOffset`.

Comment: You might want to mention what browsers you have to support.

Comment: Your issues are exactly why people use libraries such as jQuery. There's no nice way of getting the value you want without lots of browser-specific code.

Comment: Good idea ! I'm going to check it !

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, Thanks for the edit, IE9, FF and Chrome. That's it.  :)

Comment: @Phylogenesis, I know, but mostly everything else was in JS, so I wanted to get the rid off jQuery for this page :)

Comment: @Phylogenesis OP only has to support modern browsers. It's likely as simple with the DOM API.

Comment: @Merqurio You could always look at the jQuery implementation of `.offset()` and only use that part.

Comment: @Jonathan in [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/f7e60dc83d81cbf892de9dab39642dd67c49bd23/src/offset.js#L161) scrollTop is pageYOffset also, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function getPosition(element) {
  var xPosition = 0,
    yPosition = 0;

  while (element) {
    xPosition += (element.offsetLeft + element.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (element.offsetTop + element.clientTop);
    element = element.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPosition,
    y: yPosition
  };
}

function getScroll() {
  return {
    x: document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft,
    y: document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
  };
}

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var pos = getPosition(this),
    scroll = getScroll(),
    diff = (pos.x - scroll.x) + ',' + (pos.y - scroll.y);

  this.childNodes[0].nodeValue = diff;
  console.log(diff);
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
}
#test {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 300px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>Element</div>
```

### Summary:

A final function set might look like this:

```
function getPosition(element) {
    var xPosition = 0,
        yPosition = 0;

    while (element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    return {
        x: xPosition,
        y: yPosition
    };
}

function getScroll() {
    return {
        x: document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft,
        y: document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
    };
}

function getWindowOffset(element) {
    var pos = getPosition(element),
    scroll = getScroll();

    return {
            x: (pos.x - scroll.x),
            y: (pos.y - scroll.y)
    };
}
```

Then just call `getWindowOffset()` on your element to get its position relative to the window.

Comment: I have tried with `element.offsetTop + element.clientTop`, but I'm getting a different value too :S

Comment: I'll update in a sec. getPosition gets the value relative to the page, not the window.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this :

```
var rect = figure.getBoundingClientRect(),
    topSelected = (rect.top + (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTo)) - window.pageYOffset;
```

What it does is to check the value of `document.documentElement.scrollTop`. In Chrome this always returns 0. So if 0 is returned, `document.body` is given as element to the `scrollTop`function outside the parenthesis.

*TL;DR*

To get the offset correctly:
**Firefox** --> document.documentElement
**Chrome** --> document.body

Comment: Better method: `document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop`: If documentElement is 0, checks body; if body is 0, uses zero.

Comment: True !! Even better !